# SpringSecurity не позволяет отправить ответ хотя стоит permitAll

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

SecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/secured").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/info").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManager -> sessionManager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception{
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

JwtTokenUtils

```
@Component
public class JwtTokensUtils {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;


    private Duration jwtLifeTime = Duration.ofMinutes(30);


    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        Map<String, List<String>> claims = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> rolesList = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
        claims.put("roles", rolesList);

        Date issuedDate = new Date();
        Date expiredDate = new Date(issuedDate.getTime() + jwtLifeTime.toMillis());
        return Jwts.builder().signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).claims().add(claims).subject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .issuedAt(issuedDate).expiration(expiredDate).and().compact();
    }


    public String getUsername(String token){
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).getSubject();
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(String token){
        return getAllClaimsFromToken(token).get("roles", List.class);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token){
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }
}
```

AuthController

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final JwtTokensUtils jwtTokensUtils;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authRequest){
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword()));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new AppError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Username or password is incorrect"),
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        System.out.println(authRequest.getUsername());
        UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(authRequest.getUsername());
        String token = jwtTokensUtils.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));

    }
}
```

Я получаю статус 401
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было убрать @EnableWebSecurity